# An inequality for certain positive-semidefinite matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $G=(G_{ij})$ is a positive-semidefinite symmetric matrix with the diagonal entries all equal $1$ and all off-diagonal entries $\le0$. Does it then necessarily follow that
$$\sum_{i,j}(G^5)_{ij}\le\sum_{i,j}(G^3)_{ij}\,?$$

This is true if it is additionally assumed that all off-diagonal entries of $G$ are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I have not committed any mistake, please, find below a counter-example.

> **Counter-example.** Let $G\in \mathbb{S}^3_{+}$ be defined by
> $$
> G = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & -\frac{2}{5} & 0 \\
> -\frac{2}{5} & 1 & -\frac{2}{5}\\
> 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & 1
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$

Comment: $\frac{2}{5}$ replaced with $\frac{1}{2}$ works too.

Comment: Mark, thank you for the edit. @PeterMueller, indeed. And it works for 1/3 as well, but it fails (i.e., the inequality holds true), e.g., for $1/5$. Not clear at this point for me what would be a 'good' sufficient condition for this inequality to hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, thank you.